# how to add a second section in a tableView depending on a bool value Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, sections

I'm trying to add a second section to my tableView. I want to be able to transfer the row from section 1 when the checkbox inside the cell is pressed and make it appear in the second section and vice versa.

I searched on the forum and found only how to sort sections by date.

Please check my commented lines to understand where I have questions.

here is what I have

```cs
var cellItemData = [String]() //this is my main table data
var checkedCells = Array(count: cellItemData.count, repeatedValue:false) // this is where I assign false to all my unchecked rows in section 0
var secondSectionData = [String]() //this is where I store the cells for the second section



func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 2
 }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->     Int{

       if section == 0 {
     return cellItemData.count
                       }
       if section == 1 {
     secondSectionData.count
                       } 
       return 0
   }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell       

           if checkedCells[indexPath.row] == false{

        cell.checkBoxImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"unchecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)

        } else if checkedCells[indexPath.row] == true {

        cell.checkBoxImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"checked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)

        }

       cell.textLabel?.text = cellItemData[indexPath.row]
       // what about the cells in the other section?

       cell.checkBoxImage.tag = indexPath.row

       cell.checkBoxImage?.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTouched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

 func buttonTouched(sender: UIButton){

     for item in cellItemData {
        var i = 0
        if checkedCells[i] == true
        {
            secondSectionData.append(item)

            //tableView!.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection:1)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
            //self.tableView.reloadData()
            //not sure if this is the right way
            i++

        }
    }

   let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)) as TableViewCell
    cellItemData.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
    checkedCells.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
    tableView!.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection:0)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    self.tableView.reloadData()

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

In

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return 2
 }
```

add condition so you will have :

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   if( secondSectionData && secondSectionData.count > 0)
       return 2
   else
       return 1
 }
```

For your concern in the comment:

> // what about the cells in the other section?

This method will go through all sections and rows. How to get then your data here? well, simply check if indexPath.section is 1 or 2.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> TableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell       

           if checkedCells[indexPath.row] == false{

        cell.checkBoxImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"unchecked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)

        } else if checkedCells[indexPath.row] == true {

        cell.checkBoxImage.setImage(UIImage(named:"checked"),forState:UIControlState.Normal)

        }
       if(indexPath.section== 1)
           cell.textLabel?.text = cellItemData[indexPath.row]
       else
           cell.textLabel?.text = secondSectionData[indexPath.row]
       // what about the cells in the other section?

       cell.checkBoxImage.tag = indexPath.row

       cell.checkBoxImage?.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTouched:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure you have read my question until the end..this doesn't show how to hide the cells and how to enter it into the second section after I press the checkbox inside the cell.
Also numberOfSectionsInTableView requires a return so if you put a condition in there it has to be in the brackets {} therefore I guess I have to add another return 0, also you can't compare secondSectionData && secondSectionData.count, they are different types, string and bool.
Also if(indexPath.row == 1) returns the index of the row not the section....

Comment: well you do reload data after selecting one of the items, right? so you can just remove it from one array and add it to another. Another thing is that you don't compare secondsectiondata with count of it, you are checking if secondsection data exists, and if there are some elements inside it. sorry for row, will edit

Comment: Thank you!, my question was unclear from the beginning and I edited way too much in my app since then and at this point I have way more questions because my app is more complicated than the example. You were right about if(indexPath.section== 1) or 0. I didn't know indexPath has the value of the section it's in.